# Splash Screen Causing -- Run-Time Error 453: "Can't find DLL entry point FindWindowA in user32"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user of a excel vba macro getting the following error:

Run-Time Error 453: "Can't find DLL entry point FindWindowA in user32"

This one user is the only one out of a handful of testers getting this error. Any ideas what might be causing this? I am assuming the error is stemming from this API function:

```
Public Declare Function FindWindowA _
                   Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                   ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
```

[HERE IS THE TUTORIAL WHERE THE CODE CAME FROM -- TUTORIAL TO MAKE AN EXCEL SPLASH SCREEN](https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/create-awesome-excel-splash-screen-for-your-spreadsheet/)

Any help with this would be great! Not sure what is going wrong for her. 
Thanks!

Comment: FWIW a splash screen that's shown without any actual work getting done and disappears after a preset number of seconds, is just plain obnoxious. Anyway, what specific version and bitness of Excel is the error being thrown for?

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon   I use the splash screen to show users some basic reminders and instructions the first 10 times they open the worksheet (my end users aren't exactly saavy).   But the problem PC is running 64 bit Excel 2013.

Comment: And the other machines are running 32-bit earlier Excel? You'll need to wrap all `Declare` statements with `#If VBA7` conditional-compilation logic to include the `PtrSafe` keyword as needed, and using `LongPtr` instead of `Long`. As for instructions, consider just having an "Instructions" worksheet, that can be activated automatically, or just the first 10 times they open the workbook.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I tried adding the conditional compilation logic as you described, but the error persists. Also, we are all running 64 bit excel so the issue is not related to that. Any more ideas? I appreciate the help!